# SQL Query ,How to show result in row wise format?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello guys I have a sql query that finds sum of columns between some ranges.
The query is below

`select 
    sum(case when rating_value between 0 and 1.9 then 1 end)  as Poor,
    sum(case when rating_value between 2 and 2.9 then 1 end) as Average,
    sum(case when rating_value between 3 and 3.9 then 1 end) as Good,
    sum(case when rating_value between 4 and 5 then 1 end) as Very_Good
    from rating`

which outputs like this

`poor   |  good | verygood | average
 39     |  131  | 231      | 552`

But  i want output like this

```
Rating |  Count or Value
-----------------------
Poor        31
Good        21
Average     552
very good   231
```

Hoping for a positive reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` with a `case` statement:

```
select (case when rating_value between 0 and 1.9 then 'Poor'
             when rating_value between 2 and 2.9 then 'Average'
             when rating_value between 3 and 3.9 then 'Good'
             when rating_value between 4 and 5 then 'Very_Good'
        end) as grp, count(*)
from rating
group by grp
order by min(rating_value);
```

Comment: Thank .. Gordon it worked.   Sorry cant vote up  for this answer bcoz i dont have much reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this..

```
select 
(case when rating_value between 0 and 1.9 then 'Poor' 
case when rating_value between 2 and 2.9 then  'Average'
case when rating_value between 3 and 3.9 then 'Good'
case when rating_value between 4 and 5 then 'Very_Good'
end) as rate, count(*) AS cnt
from rating
group by rate
order by cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNPIVOT as below

```
SELECT Rating,Value FROM(

select 10  as Poor,20 as Average,45 as Good,15 as Very_Good /*Your Query*/

) AA
UNPIVOT
(Value FOR Rating IN ([Poor],[Average],[Good],[Very_Good])) BB
```

Answer (score 0):

The same as previous answers, just not using between to make the code with less letters :)

```
SELECT
    ( CASE WHEN rating_value < 2 THEN 'Poor'
           WHEN rating_value < 3 THEN 'Average'
           WHEN rating_value < 4 THEN 'Good'
           WHEN rating_value <= 5 THEN 'Very_Good'
      END ) AS rate ,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    rating
GROUP BY
    grp
ORDER BY
    1;
```